# Defining Multiple Elements of a Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: ada

In Ada, when you declare a array, you can do something like

```
    Work_Day : constant array (Day) of Boolean := (Mon .. Fri => True, Sat | Sun => False);
```

which utilizes the .. and | symbols to account for multiple elements of the array instead of having to reference each array.

I want to do something similar, but with a array of arrays, and I dont want to do it at the declaration, but instead later in the program, when I might have to redefine the initial value. I am attempting to do something like

```
   -- Set elements 2 through 5 of row 1 to asdf
   Array_of_Arrays(1)(2..5) := "asdf";
```

or

```
   -- Set elements 1 and 3 of row 1 to asdf2
   Array_of_Arrays(1)(1 | 3) := "asdf2"
```

But neither seem to be the correct syntax. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The syntax

```
Array_of_Arrays(1)(2..5) := "asdf";
```

is legal, assuming that what you have is *really* an array of arrays.  However, I'm guessing that you don't.  Unlike some languages (C, Java, etc.), Ada makes a distinction between multi-dimensional arrays and "arrays of arrays".  A two-dimensional array is declared something like

```
type Array_Type is array (1 .. 10, 1 .. 5) of Character;
Array_2D : Array_Type;
```

(and similarly for 3- or higher-dimensional arrays).  When you declare your array type like this, you use indexes separated by commas to refer to a single element:

```
Array_2D (2, 3) := 'x';
```

and not

```
Array_2D (2) (3) := 'x';  -- wrong!!  will not compile
```

You can't use a slice for multi-dimensional arrays:

```
Array_2D (1, 2..5) := "asdf";
```

The language designers just didn't allow that.

An array of arrays would be declared like:

```
type Array_Row is array (1 .. 5) of Character;
type Array_Of_Array_Type is array (1 .. 10) of Array_Row;
Array_Of_Arrays : Array_Of_Array_Type;
```

Now, since the array row type is separate, you don't use the multi-dimensional array syntax.  To get at one character, you'd use something like

```
Array_Of_Arrays (2) (3) := 'x';
```

and it's legal to do something like

```
Array_Of_Arrays (1) (2..5) := "asdf";
```

but not

```
Array_Of_Arrays (1, 2..5) := "asdf";  -- syntax error
```

The key is to remember that in this case, each "row" of the array is a separate array object with its own array type; while in the multi-dimensional case, rows don't have their own types.

You can use either one; there are some cases where an array of arrays may be more appropriate, and some where a multi-dimensional array is more appropriate.

Since String is an array type, this also is an array of arrays:

```
type Array_Of_Strings is array (1 .. 10) of String(1..5);
```

and this is legal:

```
A : Array_Of_Strings;

A (3) (4) := 'y';
```

but not

```
A (3, 4) := 'y';         -- illegal
```

Comment: I actually did do an array of arrays, like you declared. My  'Array_Row' is declared to be of type String though, instead of character. Could that be why it still wont compile?

Comment: Could you post the complete code (all relevant declarations, and the exact statement that got the error), and the error message that the compiler gave you?